# Watch OS 2 Simulator Heart Beat

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I was wondering if it is possible to simulate a heart beat in the Apple Watch Simulator, and if so, how to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just make yourself a textbox and enter heart rate values you want, then delete it all after testing.

Answer (score 3):

yes you need to start a sample workout session using

```
HKWorkoutSession
```

Comment: Despite the downvote, this does appear to be the correct answer. Fake heartrate data starts coming in when you start a workout.